# Not able to restore nuget for asp.net core 2.0 by using docker

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, asp.net-core, nuget

I am not able to build image due to failing of restoration of private nuget.
Below is my compose file:

> FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build AS builder

```
WORKDIR /source 
WORKDIR solnname

RUN ["cp", "../NuGet.Config","/root/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config"]  
RUN dotnet restore    
RUN dotnet publish --output /app/ --configuration Release    # build runtime
```

> image FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder/app . 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "solnname.dll"]
```

And I have defined my own NuGet.Config in same folder as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration>   
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="LocalPackage" value="http://localhost:58222/nuget" />
    <add key="Test Source" value="c:\packages" />
 </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

But getting error that

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.3/NuGet.targets(103,5): error : The local source '/sou
>   rce/c:\packages' doesn't exist. [/source/solnname.csproj]

Comment: This isn't related to Nuget or ASP.NET Core itself. You added *your own* source called `Test Source` that targets a local folder. Does that folder exist?

Comment: Are you trying to map an external folder to `c:\packages` perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Linux containers on a Windows environment then the local packages path is not going to be valid since you are using a backslashes to your local package path which is not valid in the Linux container. You will need to mount the path and change the resolution using forward slashes.